# Using Zomato Api with Retrofit

Tags: java, android, api, retrofit, zomato-api

I am trying to retrieve a list of restaurants from Zomato Api using RetroFit but I am only getting null responses and I can´t find what I did wrong.I already tried to change `@Header` to `@Query` and changing the response type from ApiResponse to `List<Restaurant>` but the problem persists.

This is an example of the response of a call to the /search endpoint of ZomatoApi

```
"results_found": 4072,
  "results_start": 0,
  "results_shown": 1,
  "restaurants": [
    {
      "restaurant": {
        "R": {
          "has_menu_status": {
            "delivery": -1,
            "takeaway": -1
          },
          "res_id": 17836294,
          "is_grocery_store": false
        },
        "apikey": "75be9f9e2239fe637bf9cb1b46979d91",
        "id": "17836294",
        "name": "Cervejaria Meia Banana",
        "url": "https://www.zomato.com/porto/cervejaria-meia-banana-coimbrões?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1",
        "location": {
          "address": "Avenida do Infante Dom Henrique, 178, Coimbrões, Vila Nova de Gaia",
          "locality": "Coimbrões",
          "city": "Porto",
          "city_id": 311,
          "latitude": "41.1213507499",
          "longitude": "-8.6152520031",
          "zipcode": "",
          "country_id": 164,
          "locality_verbose": "Coimbrões, Porto"
        },
        "switch_to_order_menu": 0,
        "cuisines": "Portuguese, Finger Food, Petiscos",
        "timings": "08:00 to 24:00 (Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Sun), 08:00 to 02:00 (Fri-Sat)",
        "average_cost_for_two": 35,
        "price_range": 3,
        "currency": "€",
        "highlights": [
          "Lunch",
          "Debit Card",
          "Breakfast",
          "Dinner",
          "Indoor Seating",
          "Wine",
          "Fullbar",
          "Beer"
        ],
        "offers": [],
        "opentable_support": 0,
        "is_zomato_book_res": 0,
        "mezzo_provider": "OTHER",
        "is_book_form_web_view": 0,
        "book_form_web_view_url": "",
        "book_again_url": "",
        "thumb": "https://b.zmtcdn.com/data/res_imagery/17836294_RESTAURANT_2d9d944dfca0415414fdfeca7522c396.jpg?fit=around%7C200%3A200&crop=200%3A200%3B%2A%2C%2A",
        "user_rating": {
          "aggregate_rating": "3.4",
          "rating_text": "Average",
          "rating_color": "CDD614",
          "rating_obj": {
            "title": {
              "text": "3.4"
            },
            "bg_color": {
              "type": "lime",
              "tint": "500"
            }
          },
          "votes": 24
        },
        "all_reviews_count": 10,
        "photos_url": "https://www.zomato.com/porto/cervejaria-meia-banana-coimbrões/photos?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1#tabtop",
        "photo_count": 30,
        "menu_url": "https://www.zomato.com/porto/cervejaria-meia-banana-coimbrões/menu?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1&openSwipeBox=menu&showMinimal=1#tabtop",
        "featured_image": "https://b.zmtcdn.com/data/res_imagery/17836294_RESTAURANT_2d9d944dfca0415414fdfeca7522c396.jpg",
        "has_online_delivery": 0,
        "is_delivering_now": 0,
        "store_type": "",
        "include_bogo_offers": true,
        "deeplink": "zomato://restaurant/17836294",
        "is_table_reservation_supported": 0,
        "has_table_booking": 0,
        "events_url": "https://www.zomato.com/porto/cervejaria-meia-banana-coimbrões/events#tabtop?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1",
        "phone_numbers": "22 3792953",
        "all_reviews": {
          "reviews": [
            {
              "review": []
            },
            {
              "review": []
            },
            {
              "review": []
            },
            {
              "review": []
            },
            {
              "review": []
            }
          ]
        },
        "establishment": [
          "Casual Dining"
        ],
        "establishment_types": []
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

### Api Interface

```
public interface ZomatoApi {
    @GET("search")
    Call<ApiResponse> getNearbyRestaurants(@Query("lat") double lat, @Query("lon") double lon,
                        @Query("count") int count,@Query("radius") double radius, @Header("api_key") String apiKey);
}
```

### ApiResponse Class

```
package com.cmuteam.app;

import java.util.List;

public class ApiResponse {
        private String results_found;
        private String  results_start;
        private String results_shown;
        private List<Restaurant> restaurants;

    public ApiResponse(String results_found, String results_start, String results_shown, List<Restaurant> restaurants) {
        this.results_found = results_found;
        this.results_start = results_start;
        this.results_shown = results_shown;
        this.restaurants = restaurants;
    }

    public String getResults_found() {
        return results_found;
    }

    public String getResults_start() {
        return results_start;
    }

    public String getResults_shown() {
        return results_shown;
    }

    public List<Restaurant> getRestaurants() {
        return restaurants;
    }
}
```

### Restaurant Class

```
package com.cmuteam.app;

public class Restaurant {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    Location location;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public Restaurant(String id, String name, Location location) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.location = location;
    }
}
```

### Location Class

```
public class Location {
    private String address;
    private String latitude;
    private String longitude;

    public Location(String address, String latitude, String longitude) {
        this.address = address;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public String getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public String getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }
```

### Fragment where i make the Api call

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        context = getContext();
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        restaurantsList= new ArrayList<>(50);
        getApi().getNearbyRestaurants(41.12108,-8.615718100000002,20,10000,"75be9f9e2239fe637bf9cb1b46979d91")
                .enqueue(new Callback<ApiResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<ApiResponse> call, Response<ApiResponse> response) {
                        List<Restaurant> restaurants=response.body().getRestaurants();
                        mAdapter = new RestaurantAdapter(context, restaurantsList);
                        RecyclerView.ItemDecoration itemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(context, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL);
                        mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(itemDecoration);
                        for (int i = 0; i < restaurants.size(); i++) {
                            restaurantsList.add(new Restaurant(restaurants.get(i).getId(),restaurants.get(i).getName(),restaurants.get(i).getLocation()));
                            mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(i);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<ApiResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                        builder.setMessage("Couldn´t find any nearby restaurants");
                        AlertDialog mDialog = builder.create();
                        mDialog.show();
                    }
                });
    }

@Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View mContentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.poi_list, container,false);
        mRecyclerView = mContentView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mContentView.getContext()));
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        return mContentView;
    }

    private Retrofit getRetrofit(){
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }

    private ZomatoApi getApi(){
        return  getRetrofit().create(ZomatoApi.class);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The authorization header is called "user-key" not "api_key" as mentioned in zomato docs.

Comment: ir worked but now says I don't have an adapter attached

Comment: in addition to the header issue you will face another issue; the Restaurant class is not mapping the Restaurant object returning from json response.

Comment: why is it not mapping?

Comment: you should set the adapter to your recyclerview  recyclerview.setAdapter(adapter)

Comment: They are completely two different objects

Comment: I did set it in the onCreateView method

Comment: Mohamed Hesham I only need the id,name and location, do I have to put them all as attributes in my class?

Comment: The adapter is set to recycler view before it is already initialized, the adapter is initialized after response returns from api so in onCreateView it will be set to null

Comment: regarding object mapping you can use this website jsonschema2pojo.org to make sure your mapping is correct ... it will generate pojo files for you.

Comment: So I should change my setAdapter to the response?

Comment: definitely ...you should set it after receiving the response.

Comment: I am not sure how the website works. Do I have to put my response on the left and in the source type choose JSON schema?

Comment: yes but set count to 1 restaurant only to be able for the website to parse the json response

Comment: Thanks, you were really helpful